# How to install JRE on ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: java, jre

I have Java version 1.7.0_91 installed in my Ubuntu PC. I installed it using the command

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

so, I think only JDK is installed but not the JRE. So what can I do to install JRE?

Comment: Just run `sudo apt-get install default-jre`

Comment: this didn't work

Comment: Why do you think the JRE isn't installed?

Comment: bcause I didn't find jre location for android studio and sql workbench installation

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default
```

This will install Oracle JRE 8 and set it as default.

Comment: Some explanation of what your commands do might be helpful :). It may be obvious to you, but not to the OP or others who see this answer.